# MySQL: Why can't I INSERT multiple values INTO my table?

Tags: mysql, insert

My first time using MySQL.  I can only INSERT a single value at a time, but if I try to copy/paste my whole list of values I get an error.

I have a table (nation) with two columns, the first is PK (nation_id) and is set to INT AUTO INCREMENT and the second is (nation_name) set to VARCHAR 100.

With the statement below I get: ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
INSERT INTO nation ( nation_name )
    VALUES
    ('Afghanistan',
    'Albania',
    'Algeria',
    'Andorra',
    'Angola',
    'Antigua and Barbuda',
    'Argentina');
```

What am I doing wrong?  How do I INSERT my whole list of nations in one statement?

Comment: `NSERT INTO nation ( nation_name )
    VALUES
    ('Afghanistan'),
    ('Albania'),
    ('Algeria'),
    ('Andorra'),
    ('Angola'),
    ('Antigua and Barbuda'),
    ('Argentina');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose every value with opening & closing brackets then separate them with commas:

```
INSERT INTO nation ( nation_name )
    VALUES
    ('Afghanistan'),
    ('Albania'),
    ('Algeria'),
    ('Andorra'),
    ('Angola'),
    ('Antigua and Barbuda'),
    ('Argentina');
```